# How can I reduce memory usage with a very large Ruby hash?

Tags: ruby, memory, hash

I have a text file that contains a million entries. Each entries is basically a couple of sentences averaging twenty words.

In order to do a few tasks, I'm loading all the words into a hash. Each word is a key and the value will be the number of times it is present in the text.

My problem is that I'm running out of memory when loading them into the hash. I'm on a machine that has only has 1 GB of RAM. Is there a way to reduce memory usage? Or should I go with something other than a Ruby hash.

Comment: Without knowing more about the tasks it is very hard to give you advice. For example, do the tasks require random access to the data or linear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Avoiding Large In-Memory Data Structures

By definition, an in-memory data structure uses memory. If you are memory-constrained, consider using a database or seekable on-disk file for your storage needs.

#### A Few Options

You may want to look into SQLite3, Redis, or a key/value store of some sort. Whatever you go with, though, the idea is to trade disk I/O for memory consumption.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use a in-memory tree data structure (TRIE)

I'd suggest avoiding large in-memory data structures, but if you still need / want to manage big data structures with text you may find interesting the [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (Tree where descendants of a node have a common prefix of the string associated with that node)

Have a look at these github projects:

1. https://github.com/dustin/ruby-trie
2. https://github.com/tyler/trie

Answer (score 2):

Why not using GDBM?
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.6/libdoc/gdbm/rdoc/GDBM.html

Is part of the standard lib since 1.8.6. I don't think you have an older version of Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

If this text file is unchanging (perhaps even if it isn't), i'd suggest making it into a [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org) database instead of in-memory hash.